# TextBox.value copy in .Cell as double | copying ignores commas

Tags: vba, excel

Hello guys I have problem with copying value calculated and stored in `Me.TextBox` to cell.
Value is as double like `1.11` but when I try to copy it to cell it changes to `111` ignoring commas

code is like this

```
Private Sub valuesadd_Click()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("x")

    'searching empty row
    lRow = wsf.Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
      .End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    'copying
    With ws
      .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = TextBox1.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub CALC_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("y")

    Calc.TextBox1.Text = Cstr(ws.Cells(A.ListIndex, 1).Value * B.Value) 
End Sub
```

so I try to `msgbox TextBox1.Value` and it says like `1,11` after and before copying but when it comes to `With ws.Cells(lRow, 3).Value` and I try to msgbox that cell it is as `111`

WHY?!
what am I doing wrong

Comment: and yes i know that cstr is a string value, still it ignores commas anyway. I also tried Calc.TextBox1.Value = Cdbl(...)

Comment: Is the dot your decimal separator? or it's the comma? Try replacing the dot with a comma and then copy to range

Comment: Maybe something like `.Cells(lRow, 3).Value = CDbl(Replace(TextBox1.Value, ".", ","))`

Comment: use `Debug.Print Application.DecimalSeparator` to see if your decimal separator is comma or dot. The decimal separator you enter in the TextBox must be the same.

Comment: .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = CDbl(Replace(TextBox1.Value, ".", ",")) 
helps. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the correct decimal separator was entered in the TextBox.

```
Application.DecimalSeparator 'gives the correct separator
```

So if you use:

```
TextBox1.Value = Replace(TextBox1.Value, ".", Application.DecimalSeparator)
TextBox1.Value = Replace(TextBox1.Value, ",", Application.DecimalSeparator)
With ws
    .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Cdbl(TextBox1.Value)
End With
```

it is independent from your localization. You can either input a `,` or a `.` and both will result in the correct decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Cells(lRow, 3).Value = CDbl(Replace(TextBox1.Value, ".", ","))
```

helps,
also found workaround

```
Calc.TextBox1.Value = Cdbl(...)
```

and

```
 With ws
      .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Cdbl(TextBox1.Value)
    End With
```

i don't have idea why it have to be 2 times.